# Pressing Enter Key in input type text isn't working

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="adminstudent.php" enctype="form-data/multipart">    
    <input type="text" id="searchStudent" class="form-control" name="txtsearch" placeholder="Search Student...">
    <input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="Search" class="btn btn-warning">
</form>
```

and JQUERY to trigger if ENTER KEY is pressed

```
$('#searchStudent').keypress(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#btnsearch').click();
    }
});
```

But it just refresh when I pressed Enter Key.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to develop a feature that is already implemented in all browsers since ages?

Just drop the jQuery altogether and leave the form as such. As long as you have have a `<form>` tag enclosing an `<input type="submit" value="Send"/>` (or `<button type="submit">Send</button>`), pressing the `Enter` key in any of the `inputs` will submit the form.